# How to continue smoothing after subdivision surface is already applied

Tags: mesh, smooth

Can you tell me how can I get rid of the bumps and dents and make the object in the picture smoother and look closer to sphere at the top and on the sides (like a light bulb)? I already applied subdivision surface modifier but it does nothing to get rid of the bigger bumps and dents. [image]. I made this by first applying subdivision surface modifier to a cube and then scaling up the upper parts and scaling down lower parts. This is what i get but I want to make it look better without bumps and dents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The topology of a cube after a subdivision has been applied is still a cube, just with more geometry and in a rounder shape. If you want the shape at the top to be rounder you have a few options, just bear in mind that you can only push the existing cube geometry so far into the shape of a sphere.

#### Smooth vertices

[image: example geometry with smooth vertices]

[Smooth vertices](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/vertex/smooth_vertices.html) and [laplacian smooth](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/vertex/laplacian_smooth.html)  are in the vertex menu of edit mode. They will relax the geometry a bit and make faces more even.

#### To Sphere

[image: side by side comparison of to sphere]

[To Sphere](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/transform/to_sphere.html) will take a selection and push it into a sphere. You can combine this with a smooth vertices to further tame the geo.

#### Combine a sphere

You can also add a UV sphere (matching the number of vertices around the sphere and your mesh), by deleting the top of your mesh and the bottom of your sphere and using [bridge edge loops](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/edge/bridge_edge_loops.html) you can connect the two sections.
[image]

The benefit of this method is it doesn't require you to do any repairs to the existing mesh.

Comment: thanks a lot. smooth vertices worked to a great extent (I'd say 75%), although not complete. A few questions based on your answer. 1)Laplacian smooth did nothing. Why it might be? 2) When I said transform to sphere, a big thick black circle appeared on my screen . When I moved my mouse it only greatly distorted my geometry. So I didnt do it. What is that big black sphere I have no idea. 3) I added a sphere but how can I match the number of vertices of that sphere and my existing mesh?

Comment: Since the whole of your object seems to be based on circular shapes, why didn't you start modelling with a UV Sphere instead of a cube in the first place?

Comment: Laplacian smooth has an iterations parameter, you might need to balance the effects strength and iterations. 
To sphere can be quite agressive, especially with a high dpi mouse. You can click to apply it and then drag the strength of the operator to fine tune it.

To match the vertices just count the selection (there's a setting in the interface pane which had scene data, it'll tell you how many vertices you have selected too). 

Definitely worth considering John's point, you could extrude a square section out of a UV sphere instead of the other way around.